# After installing Ubuntu I get an initramfs error

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, initramfs

I fresh installed ubuntu 20.04 with live USB, and after restart I got the following error message:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem please?

[image: Initramfs error]

[image: Initramfs error]

Comment: If you're getting a BusyBox prompt immediately after system installation, something went wrong. I suggest that you try again with the installation of Ubuntu.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to try to repair a failed "fresh" installation.  Make sure that your installation media is valid and that it passes integrity checks.

Comment: You **MAY** have a old BIOS. You **MAY** have a corrupt ramdisk file. You **MAY** have an incorrect /etc/fstab. Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you,sir.I downloaded ubuntu iso from ubuntu website and made live usb again but it doesn't worked.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you,sir.I thought my HDD had problem and I used this command to format my HDD(sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1m).Now I'm trying to installing ubuntu again.If there is an error again I will ask you,sir.By the way,Do I need to update my BIOS.

Comment: if you do not need to secure erase, and you only want to *format* your hard drive, you can save a lot of time by using `fdisk` or Gnome Disks from the live session.  If there is a BIOS update available, the best time to update the BIOS is prior to installing an operating system.  Since you are having problems, it's a good idea for you to update your BIOS.  Make sure that you obtain the correct files for your specific model motherboard and follow the manufacturer's directions for your model. Flashing the wrong firmware or interrupting the process can be catastrophic.

Comment: There wasn't a real need to use `dd` on your HDD yet. If you would have given me the data I requested, we might have been able to save you a lot of time. Now... please follow instructions... show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you,sir.I noted the command you taught me.If I get the similar error again next time I will try to use it.Now I can install and use ubuntu but BIOS error is still there.I'm using old laptop and BIOS update is available for my laptop.How can I update BIOS on ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema Thank you,sir.I appreciate your help and I'm sorry I didn't gave the data you requested on time.I need to use my laptop urgently and I found about [dd] command.That's why I used it,sir.I'm using old model of fujitsu lifebook laptop.

Comment: @heynnema My laptop model is [Fujitsu Lifebook LH531].Bios version is [1.08] (06/03/2011).Product name is [FJNBB17].Serial Number is [518125-01R1Z02495].

Comment: You **must** follow the instructions from your motherboard manufacturer when flashing your BIOS.  The process is different between manufacturers and often between different models from the same manufacturer.  A BIOS flash is not related to any operating system and since it's your motherboard firmware, you do not want to make a mistake. Read and follow the manufacturer's instructions carefully.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you,sir.

Answer (score 0):

**sda5**

/dev/sda5 is not being found. Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

**BIOS**

Fujitsu Lifebook LH531

You have BIOS version 1.08. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.15, available [here](https://www.shopfujitsu.com/CSPortal/supportsearch.do?srch=DOWNLOADS&Series=L%20Series&Model=LH531&ProductType=Notebook%20PC).

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Update #1:**

Reinstalled Ubuntu and it boots properly now. BIOS still needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you,sir.How can I update BIOS on ubuntu?

Comment: @MHT Either Windows, or via some BIOS's allow direct updates, or FreeDOS http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: Thank you,sir.I will try to update my BIOS.

Comment: @MHT Status please...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,sir.I didn't updated the BIOS yet.I think the best and easy way to update my computer BIOS is reinstall Windows 7 and use Windows 7 to update it.Problem is I only have one computer and I need to use it for my work.That's why I'm not update BIOS yet.If I update BIOS and get any error I will comment status on this post,sir.Thank you so much for asking,sir.

Comment: @MHT Did you resolve the /dev/sda5 problem yet? Is the machine booting yet? What was wrong?

Comment: The /dev/sda5 problem is solved and I only had ACPI BIOS Error on my machine,sir.After used this command [sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1m] to formatted my HDD and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 the machine is booted and worked fine now,sir.I don't know exactly what was wrong but I think it is because of my HDD.Thank you so much for asking,sir.